# Completing the diagram using latex

Tags: latex

I intend to draw the chemistry of the reaction as depicted below using chemfig. Here is what I have done studying examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-=-=(-CH=[::-90]CH_2)-=)}\rightarrow{->[$h\nu$]}[,1.5]\chemfig{*6(-=-=(-CH= [::-90]CH_2)-=)}
\end{document}
```

This is a sample of the output intended:
[image]

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/689413/36296